# FilePicker - Access denied in iframe in Internet Explorer

Tags: filepicker

I am getting an error when using filepicker as below and none of the other scripts execute on the page. The filepicker dialog does open though and file upload works. But, the scripts that I have written on page do not get executed.

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

File: comm_iframe, Line: 1, Column: 1
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

On clicking of error link, it says https://filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe

Comment: Have you found a solution?